# namespaces missing with Universal Windows application in VS Community 2015 update 1

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I am really frustrated with lot's of problems on VS Community 2015 update 1.First the problem was on missing template of Universal Windows in VS.but after a lot of try,I solved it.
Now the new issue is when creating a project on Universal Windows App from Visual C#\Windows Tab, the xaml.cs file is missing with namespaces or there are red color under namespaces.Again i tried many solutions,re-installed the Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform from NuGet manager,modified the installer package of VS from Program and Features under Control panel.
Still I didn't find it worked..Pls help me to resolve the issue...My head spinning round!!!